# How to calculate a good batch size when reading files into memory in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, filereader

In javascript, I want to read all selected user files.

I use folder select input field to get files, get the amount of cores available, and even RAM in gb, from the navigator variable.

I'm using a queue algorithm, so I create a web worker task per available core.

Then I loop through every worker, and slice off a `batch` size off the files list, and give to the worker.

Each time a worker finishes, it takes another slice of size `batch` from the files list, until there is no more files left, and all workers are finished.

I'm having trouble figuring out what is a good `batch` size value to use. It could be fixed or based off some formula.

I find that if I have 77 files, batch size of 16 works ok, and if I have 151324, then batch size of 300 is ok. But I don't wan't to pick a batch size that could kill memory, but at the same time make it faster.

Also I read at most 75 kilobytes from each file.

Also each file has a size property. Would it makes a difference, if I do any presorting?

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has to be tested, but by using [URL#createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), you could theoretically create direct pointers to the Files on the disk, available to your workers, without copying any data from the main thread.

This means that your *batch size* could be simply `files.length / numberOfWorkers`.

---

**[A rough proof of concept:](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg62pjdp/)**
<sup>(as a fiddle because StackSnippet's null origined iframe makes this trick impossible...)</sup>

In the workers:

```
self.onmessage = e => {
  Promise.all(
    e.data.map(async (url)=> 
      fetch(url).then(r=>r.blob())
    // here you can do whatever you have to do with the file
      .then(file => new FileReaderSync()
      .readAsText(file.slice(0,75))
       )
    )
  )
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
};
</script>
```

In the main page:

```js
// workers is an Array containing your WebWorkers
inp.onchange = e => {
  const urls = [...inp.files]
    .map(file => URL.createObjectURL(file));
  const batchSize = Math.ceil(urls.length / (navigator.hardwareConcurrency));
  workers.forEach((worker, i) => {
    worker.postMessage(urls.slice(i*batchSize, i*batchSize + batchSize));  
  });
};
```